# How to loop array of objects if key is dynamic in array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I want to access all values of an array of objects

```
let data = [
    { firstName1: 'a',  id: 1, email1: 'a@gmail.com'},
    { firstName2: 'b',  id: 2,  email2: 'b@gmail.com'}
  ];
```

```
 data.map(ele=> <p>{ ele.firstName}</p>)
```

result should be:

```
a
b
```

Comment: Can you precise your question? Is it about the `key` attribute?

Comment: @GabrielPichot what `key` attribute?

Comment: How would you like the keys or values output?

Comment: Key name are different :
 firstName1
firstName2

Answer (score 0):

Accessing keys dynamically

```
let data = [
    { firstName1: 'a',  id: 1, email1: 'a@gmail.com'},
    { firstName2: 'b',  id: 2,  email2: 'b@gmail.com'}
 ];

data.map(d => Object.keys(d).map(key => <p>{d[key]}</p>))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to extract key/value from objects in javascript

```
data.forEach( dataEle =>{  
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dataEle)) {
    console.log(key +": "+ value)
  } 
})
```

Or another way like this

```
data.forEach( dataEle =>{   
  Object.keys(dataEle).forEach(key =>{
     console.log(key +": "+ dataEle[key])
  })
})
```

Comment: How to I render this in jsx